# How do I collect the results of calling an async API sequentially?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have an async API that essentially returns results through pagination

```
public CompletableFuture<Response> getNext(int startFrom);
```

Each `Response` object contains a list of offsets from `startFrom` and a flag indicating whether there are more elements remaining and, therefore, another `getNext()` request to make.

I'd like to write a method that goes through all the pages and retrieves all the offsets. I can write it in a synchronous manner like so

```
int startFrom = 0;
List<Integer> offsets = new ArrayList<>();

for (;;) {
    CompletableFuture<Response> future = getNext(startFrom);
    Response response = future.get(); // an exception stops everything
    if (response.getOffsets().isEmpty()) {
        break; // we're done
    }
    offsets.addAll(response.getOffsets());
    if (!response.hasMore()) {
        break; // we're done
    }
    startFrom = getLast(response.getOffsets());
}
```

In other words, we call `getNext()` with `startFrom` at 0. If an exception is thrown, we short-circuit the entire process. Otherwise, if there are no offsets, we complete. If there are offsets, we add them to the master list. If there are no more left to fetch, we complete. Otherwise, we reset the `startFrom` to the last offset we fetched and repeat.

Ideally, I want to do this without blocking with `CompletableFuture::get()` and returning a `CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>` containing all the offsets.

How can I do this? How can I compose the futures to collect their results?

---

I'm thinking of a "recursive" (not actually in execution, but in code)

```
private CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> recur(int startFrom, List<Integer> offsets) {
    CompletableFuture<Response> future = getNext(startFrom);
    return future.thenCompose((response) -> {
        if (response.getOffsets().isEmpty()) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(offsets);
        }
        offsets.addAll(response.getOffsets());
        if (!response.hasMore()) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(offsets);
        }
        return recur(getLast(response.getOffsets()), offsets);
    });
}

public CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> getAll() {
    List<Integer> offsets = new ArrayList<>();
    return recur(0, offsets);
}
```

I don't love this, from a complexity point of view. Can we do better?

Comment: No, you can't do both. The problem is that `hasMore` is only available in the actual response, which makes it necessary to call `future.get()`, therefore to block. If you can separate the `hasNext()` check from the heavy `getNext` call, then it may become possible to make separate calls and model your async calls differently.

Comment: @ernest_k I wasn't expecting to use `get()`. I was hoping to use `thenCompose`, ie. receiving the result of `getNext`, and internally call the next `getNext()`, and "recur" as necessary.

Comment: @ernest_k Please see my edit.

Comment: The edit you made is the solution for your problem, you can't really do better. I think you could even post it as answer (and remove it from the question).

Comment: Just a thought though, if you can modify this API: in our application we have a similar case, but the async API also returns the total number of pages/records. This allows us to perform a first call, then all the remaining calls in parallel. Moreover, this kind of API does not give much advantage if your goal is always to retrieve the full list. Better return it in a single call then. At least, it should take the page size as parameter, so that you can choose a size that will return all results in, say, 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to give a shot at [EA Async](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async) on this one, as it implements Java support for [async/await](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Async/await) ([inspired from C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)). So I just took your initial code, and converted it:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> getAllEaAsync() {
    int startFrom = 0;
    List<Integer> offsets = new ArrayList<>();

    for (;;) {
        // this is the only thing I changed!
        Response response = Async.await(getNext(startFrom));
        if (response.getOffsets().isEmpty()) {
            break; // we're done
        }
        offsets.addAll(response.getOffsets());
        if (!response.hasMore()) {
            break; // we're done
        }
        startFrom = getLast(response.getOffsets());
    }

    // well, you also have to wrap your result in a future to make it compilable
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(offsets);
}
```

You then have to [instrument your code](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async#instrumenting-your-code), for example by adding

```
Async.init();
```

at the beginning of your `main()` method.

I must say: this really looks like magic!

Behind the scenes, EA Async notices there is an `Async.await()` call within the method, and rewrites it to handle all the `thenCompose()`/`thenApply()`/recursion for you. The only requirement is that your method must return a `CompletionStage` or `CompletableFuture`.

That's really *async code made easy*!

Answer (score 1):

For the exercise, I made a generic version of this algorithm, but it is rather complex because you need:

1. an initial value to call the service (the `startFrom`)
2. the service call itself (`getNext()`)
3. a result container to accumulate the intermediate values (the `offsets`)
4. an accumulator (`offsets.addAll(response.getOffsets())`)
5. a condition to perform the "recursion" (`response.hasMore()`)
6. a function to compute the next input (`getLast(response.getOffsets())`)

so this gives:

```
public <T, I, R> CompletableFuture<R> recur(T initialInput, R resultContainer,
        Function<T, CompletableFuture<I>> service,
        BiConsumer<R, I> accumulator,
        Predicate<I> continueRecursion,
        Function<I, T> nextInput) {
    return service.apply(initialInput)
            .thenCompose(response -> {
                accumulator.accept(resultContainer, response);
                if (continueRecursion.test(response)) {
                    return recur(nextInput.apply(response),
                            resultContainer, service, accumulator,
                            continueRecursion, nextInput);
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(resultContainer);
                }
            });
}

public CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> getAll() {
    return recur(0, new ArrayList<>(), this::getNext,
            (list, response) -> list.addAll(response.getOffsets()),
            Response::hasMore,
            r -> getLast(r.getOffsets()));
}
```

A small simplification of `recur()` is possible by replacing `initialInput` by the `CompletableFuture` returned by the result of the first call, the `resultContainer` and the `accumulator` can be merged into a single `Consumer` and the `service` can then be merged with the `nextInput` function.

But this gives a little more complex `getAll()`:

```
private <I> CompletableFuture<Void> recur(CompletableFuture<I> future,
        Consumer<I> accumulator,
        Predicate<I> continueRecursion,
        Function<I, CompletableFuture<I>> service) {
    return future.thenCompose(result -> {
        accumulator.accept(result);
        if (continueRecursion.test(result)) {
            return recur(service.apply(result), accumulator, continueRecursion, service);
        } else {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
    });
}

public CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> getAll() {
    ArrayList<Integer> resultContainer = new ArrayList<>();
    return recur(getNext(0),
            result -> resultContainer.addAll(result.getOffsets()),
            Response::hasMore,
            r -> getNext(getLast(r.getOffsets())))
            .thenApply(unused -> resultContainer);
}
```